# Correct form to get last uer id in laravel5

Tags: php, orm, eloquent

Good Morning ! I am developing a profile user and I have the following doubt.

I know that I get my last user which the following form

```
$full = User::orderBy('id','desc')->take(1)->get();
```

I recieve this json with this eloquent.

```
.   [{"id":58,"nif":"AAAA","name":"AAA","cognoms":"AAA","file":"uploads\/\/f0414.gif","birthday":"0000-00-00","presentacion":"descripciones","email":"nxnxbcbbcvcc@pesssdpepefgpepepep.com","idempresa":1,"id_poblacion":2254,"id_online":0,"created_at":"2015-05-24 00:00:40","updated_at":"2015-05-24 00:00:40"}]
```

But I don'n know how to get the id and sum one more.

Comment: You want to get the last inserted id ? You're already taking it as `$insert_id` and why do you want to soft the **one record** ?

Comment: Yes , I need to get the user id that I registered now.

Comment: **But I don'n know how to get the id and sum one more.** You are already getting the id and do you want to get the sum of all users ?

Comment: It was the '$insert_id' that you have taken.. Just echo the `$insert_id` it was already there.

Comment: The last form works correctly , I recieve the id of the user but I need to sum one more.

Comment: which one do you need to sum .. You want to add **1** to the last insert id ?

Comment: Yes @SulthanAllaudeen.

Comment: @jcsa: Well i have posted the answer. Is that ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just add **1**  to your variable you got as the `last inserted id`

```
$model = new User();
$model->save();
$insert_id = $model->id;  #This is the last inserted id
```

After this, just add **1** to the variable `$insert_id`

```
$next_id = $insert_id + 1;
```

If you want to fetch the last two records then

```
$full = User::orderBy('id','desc')->take(2)->get();
```

Here is the [reference documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)

Comment: This form works correctly , but I need to sum one more in                       $full = User::orderBy('id','desc')->take(1)->get();

Comment: Oh, you want to fetch the last two records ?

Comment: I don 'explain correctly , I try to repeat the answer , wit the second form I get the last id of the table user , but I get this result woth a String and i need to sum one at this id I recieve.

Comment: I can't understand it correctly **Do you want to add another element inside your json i.e. `sum` inside the json your get it by your query ?**

Comment: You can get the sum by `$total = DB::table('users')->sum('id');` and do you want to have the $total inside the json you produce using `$full = User::orderBy('id','desc')->take(1)->get();`